# nested if-and excel cleaner way

Tags: excel, function

Is there a cleaner way to do the following nested if-and function?

`=IF($B$2="";"";IF(AND($B$1="EN 13286-2";$B$2="Pequeno");G5;IF(AND($B$1="EN 13286-2";$B$2="Grande");G6;IF(AND($B$1="ASTM";$B$2="Pequeno");G7;IF(AND($B$1="ASTM";$B$2="Grande");G8)))))`

[image]

Basically I fill cells c1 and c4 and with the nested function `if-and` I get the correct result. From which AND combination, the outcome is different.
This function works fine but I would to get it cleaner maybe with a different approach.

For the previous function the outcome is 3943,3

Thank you!

Comment: Without actually see your data it is hard to recommend anything, but I believe a INDEX/MATCH would work better for you.

Comment: Now you need to choose one of the ones below to mark as correct.  Click on the check mark by the answer you used.  This will mark this question as answered.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: I will check your answer because reads text input, but both are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any text in the output from column G, you will want this formula:

```
=INDEX(C.A.!$G$6:$G$9;MATCH(1;INDEX(($C$1 = C.A.!$A$6:$A$9)*($C$4 = C.A.!$B$6:$B$9););0))
```

If the Output is number then a simple SUMIFS will work:

```
=SUMIFS(C.A.!G:G;C.A.!A:A;C1;C.A.!B:B;C4)
```

Comment: Watch your mixed semi colons and commas

Comment: @gtwebb habits habits.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The first function works fine for B1="EN 13286-2", but not for "ASTM" `=INDEX($G$5:$G$8;MATCH(1;INDEX(($B$1 = $A$5:$A$8)*($B$2 =$B$5:$B$8););0))`

Comment: @PauloPacheco then the two do not match, you may have spaces or other non printable characters in either the data or the search criteria.  Check your data.

Answer (score 1):

One way that can be used to copy over the numeric values, won't work on any text columns though.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1=C.A.!A$6:A$9)*($C$4=C.A.!B$6:B$9)*(C.A.!G$6:G$9))`

Comment: Setting text to numeric value it works really well! Thank you for the teaching!